# Правильное использование Map

Tags: map, объекты, c++

Привет! У меня проблема, создаю объект класса, засовываю его в map, все ок, но когда достаю его, объект не тот, вообще нулевой, видимо неправильно достаю, можете помочь с паравильным кодом?

**Мой код:**

```
class Client {

  public:
    unsigned long Id;
    Client (unsigned long id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
};

std::map<int, Client> ClientTable;

inline void addClient(int fd, Client client)
{
    ClientTable.insert(std::pair<int, Client>(fd, client));
}

bool GetClient(int fd, Client * client)
{
    std::map<int, Client>::iterator it;
    it=ClientTable.find(fd);
    if(it != ClientTable.end())
    {
        client = &it->second;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
 Client cl(1234567);
 addClient(1, cl);
 //ВСЕ ОК cl.Id == 1234567
}

void example()
{
 Client * client;
 if(GetClient(1, client))
 {
   // ТУТ client->Id == 0, ПОЧЕМУ??
 }
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Классическая ошибка. Передавайте указатель по ссылке

```
 bool GetClient (int fd, Client*& client)
```